# How to get Icon of Google Maps marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

With marker.getTitle() you get the title of a marker, but how can I ask for the icon?
I want to ask if the icon of a marker is set to certain drawable and if so do something.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create marker with new MarkerOptions() Like this:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.house_flag))
            .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
            .position(new LatLng(41.889, -87.622)));
```

So you can simply store this data in some linked list or hash map

Comment: getIcon does not function --> Error can't resolve method

Comment: getIcon() is in v3 which is the web api.

Comment: so how can I do it with the android api?

Answer (score 0):

Without context on why you need the Icon, it is really hard to understand why you want it.

If you just want to move the marker or change the rotation you can do that by saving a variable for the Marker.

Marker allows .setPosition(LatLng) and .setRotation(Float).

Hope this helps someone since this is an old question

Comment: I want it so I can restore the set of Markers when the MapsActivity gets destroyed and recreated, for example when you rotate your phone.

Comment: Somehow I hit this question again. Now I want it to match the color of text in the info window to the marker's color.

Comment: The idea would be to save a list of markers for manipulation as you want them but from my recent experience with the maps lib best would be to store marker details in a pojo yourself and then rebuild the markers on rotate etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Storing the list of markers doesn't help as you can't access the icon. The solution I went for is (a) setting Google Maps options to not rebuild on rotation and (b) passing the color information in the marker's text snippet (!), an ugly hack.

Comment: Sounds good. Unfortunately working with this type of lib if it does not allow what we want we cannot just go to GIT and ask the creator to add the feature. I am not sure why we cannot access the icon in the mobile sdk but JS can.